# use large size array to create element and then insert it into div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await

I have a javascript array of size 40000 containing objects like this one
[{previousId:null,id:1,nextId:2,imageName:"2017_10001018.jpg"}]

I am creating a survey form out of this. I have a function createElement(data,hide[boolean]). It will return an element that will be inserted inside the div. According to this function, only the first object will be visible rest will be hidden using CSS class "hide". Users will be navigating using the next and previous buttons to insert data in the form.

When I use for loop to call this function for each data then the page gets hanged. Is there any way that I insert data inside the dom without making the page hang?

Comment: This question will become a lot more clear when you provide a runnable snippet that acts on (let's say) 20 items (to keep it short), including the code for the function you talk about. Show us how it doesn't work now, in a way that we can *reproduce* it.

Comment: Wait, are you saying you have a form with 40000 steps? .oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `hide` to do that because it still renders 40,000 elements and it severely impacts the performance.

What you should try something like this:

```js
const data = [];
let currentItem = 0;

// Populates the data
for (let i = 0; i < 40_000; i++) {
  data.push(`item #${i}`);
}

// Render only ONE item
function createElement(item) {
  document.getElementById('currentItem').innerText = item;
}

// Replaces the current item with the next one
function onNextButtonClick() {
  // Prevent index overflows
  if (currentItem >= data.length) return;
  createElement(data[currentItem]);
  currentItem += 1;
}

// Give it an initial load to load the first item
onNextButtonClick();
```

```html
Item:
<div id="currentItem"></div>
<br />
<button onClick="onNextButtonClick()">Next</button>
```

What it does is it selects the first item in the data and render that on the page. After the user click the button and the button calls `onNextButtonClick()`, it **replaces** the old data with the new data. This way you don't render all 40,000 items.

This is not the perfect solution but it'll be much more performant than rendering 40,000 items.

If you want to go further, I think concepts like **paging** is a place to take a look at.